# First Auth Mifare Plus cards

Tags: java, android, authentication, smartcard, mifare

Does anyone have idea about `AuthenticateFirst` command with SL3 switch key?

I managed to get 16 bytes `(Kx, RndB)` response using below command:

```
|Cmd|KeyBNr|LenCap|
```

now I created a random 16-byte RndA to sent on second command with the first command response like below :

```
|Cmd|RndA + previous response(Kx, RndB)|
```

giving me Invalid `RndB’` or wrong key error.

I did some research and got to know that I've to convert `RndB` to `RndB’` before sending the second command using encryption. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Please guide me right direction as I am completely new to this!

Answer (score 0):

The RndB is rotated by 8 bits (first byte is moved to the
end of RndB), this yields to RndB' - this how I understand it